# Visualizing Tensorflow Optimized Graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand whether Tensorflow applies specific forms of optimization to my graph, for instance does it eliminate same expressions. E.g. if I have the code

```
def f(x):
   # x - tf.Tensor 
   # Some computation
   return y 

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])
y1 = f(x)
y2 = f(x)
z = y1 + y2
```

Now I want to check if `f(x)` is a determinstic function does Tensorflow figure out that it does not need to recompute `y2` or does it always do it. There are suppose to be some graph optimizations, but in tensorboard it shows the same graph as I have created. Can I see how it looks after the optimization passes?

Comment: You can always [visualize the graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graph_viz). For any operation you can check what are its inputs to see what will need to be computed in order to get some particular output.

Comment: But that is the general graph. Tensorflow does some optimization (e.g. replace matmul with the correct hardware op, constant folding, etc...) I want to see the optimized graph instead.